# What is ...props in React?

Tags: reactjs

For instance, the code in [Facebook's data table](https://github.com/facebook/fixed-data-table) uses `...props`. Can someone explain to me what it is and how it's used? I'm sure it's related to `this.props` but I'm not entirely sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html

> **What's with the weird `...` notation?**
>
> The `...` operator (or spread operator) is already supported for
>   arrays in ES6. There is also an ECMAScript proposal for Object Rest
>   and Spread Properties. We're taking advantage of these supported and
>   developing standards in order to provide a cleaner syntax in JSX.

Answer (score 0):

It is [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). This allows all of this.props to be passed to the component. The spread operator syntax is new to ES6.

Facebook's site has information regarding this [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html).

> The properties of the object that you pass in are copied onto the
>   component's props.
>
> You can use this multiple times or combine it with other attributes.
>   The specification order is important. Later attributes override
>   previous ones.